# Custom Widget: Creating a Complex Widget which provides a layout for use in the form editor

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I am attempting to create a custom widget plugin (as described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html)) which will provide some set of controls, along with a container whose layout I'd like exposed to the QT Creator's Form Editor.

Within my widget's plugin interface, I modify the isContainer() function to return true.

```
bool MyWidgetPlugin::isContainer() const
{
    return true;
}
```

And the class column of the Object Inspector for this custom widget's UI file looks similar to this:

```
- QWidget       <- The Custom Widget
| - QPushButton
| - QWidget     <- This is the widget who's layout I'd like to expose to the form editor.
```

This allows me to drop new widgets onto my custom widget in the form editor, but with no regards to layout. Newly added widgets may be dropped on top of others widgets, including those built into the custom widget, and I cannot change the layout of the custom widget.

It's apparent that the form editor currently has no way of knowing that the internal widget is intended to provide a layout, but I'm unsure of how to do this and have been unable to find examples of a custom widget that acts as a container. I have looked into the [Container Extension Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-containerextension-example.html), but it explicitly states it is intended for multipage widgets, so I'm led to believe there is a better solution for what I'm trying to achieve.

How can I create this custom widget so that the internal widget's layout is exposed to the form editor, or should I be approaching this in a different way?

---

**Update:** I was able to get the desired functionality by following through with the [Container Extension Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-containerextension-example.html) that I had been avoiding. I simply treated the widget as a multi-page widget that always returned the same page.

However, this has the undesirable side effect of enabling multi-page actions in the widget's form editor context menu, such as *insert page*. Using this action causes a small blank widget to be created that can't be interacted with and is placed in the top-right corner of the custom widget. While this is a minor issue, it is one that prevents me from posting this solution as an answer.

Comment: If you are still around, I would really love if you can elaborate on how you did implement this? I followed the same path but it doesn't work on my side, I can drop Widgets in the container but they don't show in the tree and I can't give them a layout

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have access to the code base I implemented this in. That said, I didn't do anything beyond what is laid out in the container extension example to get the functionality to work. Something that did bite me from time to time is making sure the plugin's doXml function provides an addPageMethod definition within it.

Comment: Can I remove the addPage() removePage() functions? Do you remember if I still need addWidget() and what widget() should return? Thanks a lot

Comment: Without addPage() the editor doesn't know how to insert that first layout. Apart from that I don't remember, and would err on the side of caution. I recommend implementing everything as described to get it working and trimming from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try that!

Comment: I made it, thanks again. The trick was that the container should not be created manually but by designer: I had to store and return the QWidget* sent by addPage()

Comment: I only one question left, do you know how to automatically create a Layout within the added Widget?

Comment: Automatically? No. From what I remember you had to add a widget to the container before it let you set the layout type, but again, I'm running off memory from a couple of years ago at this point.

Comment: Sorry I found 10mins after posting. You can automatically set the layout but you have to do so in the xml returned by domXml()